# Referencing CSS in HTML

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to reference

```
/* background color */
body
{
    background: FCFFD1;
}

/* h1 color */
h1
{
    color: purple;
}
```

in my HTML document. This is in a seperate .css file as an external style sheet.

I want put it into this:

```
<body class="body">
<center><h1>ACME PRODUCTS</h1></center>
```

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will first need to create a stylesheet for your CSS and then save it, for e.g. style.css. Once you've done that, add the following code inside the `<head></head>` tags in your HTML document:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
```

Your final code inside the HTML document should look like this:

```
<html>

<head>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">

</head>

<body class="body">

     <center><h1>ACME PRODUCTS</h1></center>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: The OP has already made a css file and saved it with the right extention

Comment: @randomuser I've mentioned `style.css` just as an example.

Comment: Alright, that worked. I've gotten it to change the header color, but the page background is still unchanged.

Comment: @onikouzou you need to add a `#` before your `background` color code inside your stylesheet, this is how it should be: `body { background: #FCFFD1; }`

Comment: Oh wow, I totally missed that! Easy fix!

Comment: @onikouzou HEX values (or colour codes) always have to have a `#` before them when used inside CSS. Also please mark my answer as the correct one since it has solved your problem. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Use this in your head tag: `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="name.css">`

Comment: A little more explanation would be helpful, since the OP does not understand how stylesheets work.

Answer (score 0):

You should check [CSS selectors](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp).

In your example code you have class specified for body HTML tag but you never call it in CSS (notice that classes are referenced like ".body"). So class atribute on body tag is not needed here. Also you should use "background-color" and not only "background". 
Check this [examples](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_background.asp).

And finally check [this example](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_link.asp) to learn how to link CSS to your HTML.

I'd edit your code as following:

```
/* background color */
body
{
    background-color: #FCFFD1;
}

/* h1 color */
h1
{
    color: purple;
}
```

and

```
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="theme.css">
</head>
<body>
    <center><h1>ACME PRODUCTS</h1></center>
```